# How to access the Overlay object boundingMapRect at the OverlayView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, mapkit, overlay

I'm trying to place images on top of Google Maps and I'm having trouble to fetch the overlay's boundingMapRect.
The odd thing is that when I check the 'overlay' with the debugger the correct data   is
 there, but when I try to print it - its garbage.

This is the printing code:

```
MKMapRect overlayRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
NSLog(@"\n\n\n");
NSLog(@"drawMapRect: overlay: x: %f, y: %f, w: %f, h: %f", 
      MKMapRectGetMinX([overlay boundingMapRect]),
      MKMapRectGetMinY([overlay boundingMapRect]),
      MKMapRectGetWidth([overlay boundingMapRect]),
      MKMapRectGetHeight([overlay boundingMapRect]));
NSLog(@"drawMapRect: boundingMapRect x: %f, boundingMapRect y: %f, boundingMapRect w: %f, boundingMapRect h: %f",
      [overlay boundingMapRect].origin.x,
      [overlay boundingMapRect].origin.y,
      [overlay boundingMapRect].size.width,
      [overlay boundingMapRect].size.height);
NSLog(@"drawMapRect: boundingMapRect x: %f, boundingMapRect y: %f, boundingMapRect w: %f, boundingMapRect h: %f",
      self.overlay.boundingMapRect.origin.x,
      ((MKOverlayView *)self).overlay.boundingMapRect.origin.y,
      [overlay boundingMapRect].size.width,
      [overlay boundingMapRect].size.height);
```

It is placed at

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context.
```

Any help would be great.
A small example of image drawing over a map with Core Graphics will be awesome.

Thanks,
Tzur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

The way to access a property of a class from which I inherit is to use 'super'.
or, in my case, [super overlay].